# Locating Path in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

```
Main Folder1
   - Submain1 folder
   - filehere1.html

Main Folder2
    - image.jpg
```

I currently working on filehere.html file, what I want to do is to locate image .jpg. How to locate this via path? Any idea?

Comment: `../main_folder_2/image.jpg` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I does;nt work.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail. Give code, and a real directory structure

Answer (score 0):

To go folders back, you have to use `../` in the link. Spaces aren't recognised either, so you use `%20` for them. Therefore, the path should be: `../Main%20Folder2/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

./  Is referring to current working directory

../ will refer to parent directory

In your case files are outside of current working directory

../ Main Folder2/image.jpg. Will give u the expected result